# Select from table, and insert data to another - Multiply data -SQL

Tags: php, sql, insert, sql-delete

I have a button that will delete all users that fits into this query:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE lastlogin < ".time()." - ".$sdata['activitylimit']."*3600
```

Although, I have to take some parts of each users data, and put it into another table ("username" and "email")

How can I take the users username AND email from the table **users**, and insert it into my table "reserved_data"?

The table reserved_data looks like this:

```
id (just the id)
data (the email or username value)
type (what type of data is it((username/email)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that directly, thanks to the table layout of the `reserved_data` table. Why do you do that? Why haven't you got a `deleted_users` table, containing their username and email? That way you could do this:

```
$q1 = "INSERT INTO deleted_users (username, email) SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE lastlogin < (".time()." - ".$sdata['activitylimit']." * 3600)";

$q2 = "DELETE FROM users WHERE lastlogin < (".time()." - ".$sdata['activitylimit']." * 3600)";
```

If you won't change the table, use something like this:

```
$toDelete = mysql_query("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE lastlogin < (".time()." - ".$sdata['activitylimit']." * 3600)");

while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($toDelete))
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO reserved_data (`data`, `type`) VALUES ('" . $user['username'] . ", 'username'");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO reserved_data (`data`, `type`) VALUES ('" . $user['email'] . ", 'email'");
}

// Now perform the delete
mysql_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE lastlogin < (".time()." - ".$sdata['activitylimit']." * 3600)");
```

You see the latter requires more code and is generally a bad idea. You lose the relation between a username and its email address.

Besides, you might want to use transactions, since it's possible for one to not be included in the first query but be included in the second query. You then lose this user's data.

And perhaps you can fix all your problems by simply adding an `(in)active` column to your users table. One rarely wants to really `delete` data.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand the problem now with my table. I followed your advice and went with the deleted_users table. Seems much more logical now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Please take note of the edit, you simply might want to 'deactivate' the users, which easily can be done by adding a column indicating whether the user is active.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use on delete trigger to log data to reserved_data table. Just move your reserved_data insert to trigger

I would not recommend approach with deletion mark. You don't need it there is no requirement to restore deleted users and it brings quite much new problems.

Comment: There is a requirement to store deleted users data in my case. I'm in a business where users often cheats. By logging their usernames, emails and ip it helps a little bit.

Comment: @burnall: you can't say. If this site has like a message board, how does it display posts made by now deleted users? And what problems do you see when deleting users, especially restoring them since that requires a mere `update` statement to set `deleted` to false again?